# Unable to quit emacs with `Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, nil`

Tags: debugging, mu4e, quitting, exit

I have some customisations in `~/.emacs.el`. Today I refactored a piece that used `dolist`, `directory-files`, and `find-file`. I am now unable to quit Emacs in the normal way and I get this from the mini-buffer:

```
Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, nil
```

I only have one kill hook, which calls a function [`mu4e-mark-execute-all`](https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/c30b9fa49e6fbad61e85607d9f1b4371413326c0/mu4e/mu4e-mark.el#L376-L415) defined in [`mu4e`](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/):

```el
(require 'mu4e)
(defun mu4e-execute-marks ()
   (interactive)
   (mu4e-mark-execute-all t)
)
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'mu4e-execute-marks)
```

I understand that the LISP debugger is for evaluating expressions or functions. Can I set a stacktrace to see the cause of the error?

Comment: Where is `mu4e-execute-marks` defined?

Comment: You get a backtrace if you switch on "Enter Debugger on Error" in the "Options" menu. You can disable all kill hooks with `M-: (let (kill-emacs-hook) (kill-emacs))`.

Comment: @muffinmad It is defined in [`mu4e`](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/) and I updated the question.

Comment: @Tobias Your code to remove all hooks actually quits Emacs on macOS. You are right about "Enter Debugger on Error", that's what I wanted, and I found the culprit in `mu4e` throwing an error when it has no marks to execute, so I wrapped the call in `(condition-case ...)`. Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is the actual problem and what can I do about it?

The hash is only initialized in `mu4e-headers-mode`. Therefore, you should correct `mu4e-execute-marks` in the following way if you want to call it in `kill-emacs-hook`:

```el
(defun mu4e-execute-marks ()
   (interactive)
   (when (derived-mode-p 'mu4e-headers-mode)
     (mu4e-mark-execute-all t))
)
```

### How to debug such errors?

Switch on "Enter Debugger on Error" in the "Options"-menu.
That meu item runs the command `toggle-debug-on-error` that just toggles the value of the variable `debug-on-error` between `nil` and `t`.

First sentence of the doc of `debug-on-error`:

> Non-nil means enter debugger if an error is signaled.

The debugger includes the backtrace.

Alternatively you can instrument `mu4e-mark-execute-all` with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `edebug-on-entry` <kbd>RET</kbd> `mu4e-mark-execute-all` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

`edebug` is an interactive debugger. You can step through the function with the space button and you can display the backtrace with the menu item "Edebug"->"Views"->"Show Backtrace".

Comment: Well done. Your ELisp code executes marks when I quit Emacs from the `mu4e` mode but does not execute marks if I quit outside that mode.

Comment: The command `M-x edebug-on-entry` is unavailable on my machine. Is `edebug` available on macOS or only on Linux?

Comment: @mmorin Could you try `M-x load-library edebug.el` before calling `edebug-on-entry`?

Comment: That works and `M-x edebug-on-entry` succeeds. I enter the function that throws the error and nothing happens. If I call that same function directly, I see the error `Wrong type argument` in the mini-buffer.